# add delete link label against data in the row in window form application c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my windows application, I want to add linklabel i.e `Delete` against each record in the datagridview and I am populating datagridview from the database like below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace search
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\Contact.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public void bindDatagridview()
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from contactsinfo", connection);
            da.Fill(ds);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Delete", typeof(String));
            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                DataGridViewLinkCell lc = new DataGridViewLinkCell();
                lc.Value = r.Cells[2].Value = "Delete";
                dataGridView1[2, r.Index] = lc;
            }
            clear();
        }
        public void clear()
        {
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bindDatagridview();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code add `Delete` linkLabel against each data in the row, but when I i click on the headertext of the datagridview, `linklabel` convert into the simple text, how it is, and is there any way to add `Delete` linklabel against each data in the row.
kindly suggest me, waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the type of the Column!

```
var col = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
col.DataPropertyName = "Delete";
col.Name = "Delete";

ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(col);
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this and its working fine.

```
DataGridViewLinkColumn dgvLink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
dgvLink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
dgvLink.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
dgvLink.HeaderText = "";
dgvLink.Name = "lnk_delete";
dgvLink.LinkColor = Color.Blue;
dgvLink.TrackVisitedState = true;
dgvLink.Text = "Delete";
dgvLink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on the column header to sort the column, and see if the underline stays in the column (`dgvLink`).

This underline disappears when you try to sort the column.